# Can't get description from XML

Tags: java, xml, unicode, xml-parsing

I have used the code below. I do not have a problem with other tags but I can not get contents of description. I think there may be a problem with character set of news feed. There are Turkish characters and they may need to handled with a unicode reader. But I do not know how to achieve that.

```
public class NewsFeed {

final URL url;
static final String TITLE = "title";
static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
static final String CHANNEL = "channel";
static final String LANGUAGE = "language";
static final String COPYRIGHT = "copyright";
static final String LINK = "link";
static final String AUTHOR = "author";
static final String ITEM = "item";
static final String PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
static final String GUID = "guid";
static final String IMAGE = "image";

NewsFeed() throws XMLStreamException, MalformedURLException {

    url = new URL("http://www.haberturk.com/rss/manset.xml");
    boolean isFeedHeader = true;
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream in = read();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);

    while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

        if (event.isStartElement()) {
            String localPart = event.asStartElement().getName()
                    .getLocalPart();

            switch (localPart) {
                case ITEM:
                    if (isFeedHeader) {
                        isFeedHeader = false;
                    }
                    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                    break;
                case TITLE:
                    String title = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                    System.out.println(title + "////");
                    break;
                case DESCRIPTION:
                    String description = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                    System.out.println(description);
                    break;
                case LINK:
                    String link = getCharacterData(event, eventReader);
                    System.out.println(link);

            }
        }

    }
}

private InputStream read() {
    try {
        return url.openStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private String getCharacterData(XMLEvent event, XMLEventReader eventReader)
        throws XMLStreamException {
    String result = "";
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    if (event instanceof Characters) {
        result = event.asCharacters().getData();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, XMLStreamException {
    new NewsFeed();
}
```

}

[image: this is output]

Answer (score 0):

Why in the while block you have: event = eventReader.nextEvent();

```
while () {
    event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And you have another call of event = eventReader.nextEvent();
within method getCharacterData.

```
event = eventReader.nextEvent();
if (event instanceof Characters) {
    result = event.asCharacters().getData();
}
```

Probably that's the problem!

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks  but did you try it in code? Does it work? It didn't work when i tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        URL url = new URL("myURL");
        InputStream is=url.openStream();
        BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(brd);
```